# Using grid-template-areas with dynamic content in Gatsby

Tags: css, reactjs, graphql, css-grid, gatsby

I am trying to use CSS grid to make a layout with alternate columns on each row. The first row would have an image to the left and text to the right, the second row with the text on the left and image on the right and so on.

I tried using nth-of-type, but as the parent node (Box) repeats for each post, I think it will be very difficult.

The thing is I cannot reach all the children individually, because the content comes from GraphQL and I only have one node to deal with.

Would someone have a suggestion to accomplish this?

Thanks!

`````
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, graphql, StaticQuery } from 'gatsby'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Img from 'gatsby-image'

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 6rem;
    overflow: visible;
` 

const Title = styled.h5`
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
`

const Inner = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 3rem;

    @media (max-width: 1024px) {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-row-gap: 80px;
        padding: 1rem;
    }
`

const Box = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 6rem;
    align-items: center;

    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: "left right";

    @media (max-width: 1024px) {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-row-gap: 80px;
        padding: 1rem;
    }
`

const Content = styled.div`
        text-decoration: none;

        &:nth-of-type(even){
            grid-area: right;
        }

        &:nth-of-type(odd){
            grid-area: left;
        }

`

const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;

        :nth-of-type(even){
            grid-area: left;
        }

        :nth-of-type(odd){
            grid-area: right;
        }

`

const StyledImg = styled(Img)`
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;

    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;

        :hover {
            opacity: .7;
        }
`

const PostTitle = styled.h6`
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;

`
const Date = styled.p`  
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    display: block;
    color: #777;

`


export class Gallery extends Component {

      render(){
        return (
            <Wrapper>
            <Title>
                Works
            </Title>
                <Inner>
                {this.props.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({ node }) => (
                    <Box key={node.id} className='box'>
                        <StyledLink to={node.fields.slug}>
                            <StyledImg fluid={node.frontmatter.image.childImageSharp.fluid} />
                        </StyledLink> 
                        <Content>
                            <StyledLink to={node.fields.slug}>
                                <PostTitle>
                                    {node.frontmatter.title}{" "}
                                </PostTitle>
                            </StyledLink>
                            <Date>
                            {node.frontmatter.date}
                            </Date>
                            <p>{node.excerpt}</p>
                        </Content>
                    </Box>
                ))}
                </Inner>
            </Wrapper>
        )
    }
}

export default props => (

    <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
          allMarkdownRemark(sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }) {
              totalCount
              edges {
              node {
                  id
                  frontmatter {
                  title
                  date(formatString: "DD MMMM, YYYY")
                  image {
                  childImageSharp {
                      fluid(maxWidth: 800) {
                      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_noBase64
                      }
                  }
              }
                  }
                  fields {
                  slug
                  }
                  excerpt
              }
              }
          }
          }
    `}
    render={data => <Gallery data={data} {...props} />}
    />
)
````
`````

Answer (score 0):

With style-components, you can lift the `nth-of-type` up to `Box` to target its child:

```
const Inner = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 1rem;
`;

// declare Image & Content first, so we can use it in Box 
const Image = styled.img`
  display: block;
`;

const Content = styled.div`
  display: block;
`;

const Box = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "left right";

  & > ${Image}, 
  &:nth-of-type(even) > ${Content} {
    grid-area: left;
  }

  & > ${Content}, 
  &:nth-of-type(even) > ${Image} {
    grid-area: right;
  }
`;
```

Here's a minimal [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/31wq9p12qm)

---

Alternatively, you might consider use only a single grid:

```
const Inner = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
`;

const Image = styled.img`
  grid-column: 1;
  &:nth-of-type(even) {
    grid-column: 2;
  }
`;

const Content = styled.div`
  grid-column: 2;
  &:nth-of-type(even) {
    grid-column: 1;
  }
`;

// use fragment (<>) so box is not rendered as a div
const Box = ({ content }) => (
  <>
    <Image src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
    <Content>{`item ${content}`}</Content>
  </>
)
```

Another [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6j6o898zrw)

Comment: The first solution didn't work, unfortunately, because a new Box is generated for every post, so it stays the same every time. So I think the code will have to come from above (Inner). I will make some changes in my code to accommodate your second suggestion (and I am not so familiar with fragments yet), but you gave me some good ideas to work with. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey @Fadanabela, glad it's helpful. Did you see the codesandbox?

Comment: Yes, I did and it helped me to make it work. I just posted the answer. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Fadanabela You're welcome, I don't understand why you'd need to target from your inner comp, but perhaps there's something different about the way you set up your components. Hope you have a good time w gatsby!

Comment: It is because for every post, a new Box div is generated, so if I have 6 posts, I will have 6 Box divs, and the grid code starts from zero for each one, so the template areas print as if it is always the first row. The Inner div, stays the same and can "count" its children. I hope I could explain clearly. It is my first time with Gatsby and GraphQL. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Here's what worked for me:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, graphql, StaticQuery } from 'gatsby'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Img from 'gatsby-image'

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 6rem;
    overflow: visible;
` 

const Title = styled.h5`
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
`

const Inner = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 3rem;

    @media (max-width: 1048px) {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }

    @media (max-width: 800px) {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
`

const Box = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    column-gap: 3rem;
    align-items: center; 

    ${Inner} &:nth-child(even) {
        grid-template-areas: 
        "right left";
    }

    ${Inner} &:nth-child(odd) {
        grid-template-areas: 
        "left right";
    }
`

const Thumb = styled(Link)`
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    grid-area: left;
`

const Content = styled.div`
    text-decoration: none;
    grid-area: right;
`

const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
`

const StyledImg = styled(Img)`
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;

        :hover {
            opacity: .7;
        }
`

const PostTitle = styled.h6`
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;

`

const Date = styled.p`  
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    display: block;
    color: #777;

`

export class Gallery extends Component {

      render(){
        return (
            <Wrapper>
            <Title>
                Works
            </Title>
                <Inner>
                {this.props.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({ node }) => (
                    <Box key={node.id} className='box' >
                        <Thumb to={node.fields.slug}>
                            <StyledImg fluid={node.frontmatter.image.childImageSharp.fluid} />
                        </Thumb> 
                        <Content>
                            <StyledLink to={node.fields.slug}>
                                <PostTitle>
                                    {node.frontmatter.title}{" "}
                                </PostTitle>
                            </StyledLink>
                            <Date>
                            {node.frontmatter.date}
                            </Date>
                            <p>{node.excerpt}</p>
                        </Content>
                    </Box>
                ))}
                </Inner>
            </Wrapper>
        )
    }
}

export default props => (

    <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
          allMarkdownRemark(sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }) {
              totalCount
              edges {
              node {
                  id
                  frontmatter {
                  title
                  date(formatString: "DD MMMM, YYYY")
                  image {
                  childImageSharp {
                      fluid(maxWidth: 800) {
                      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                        base64
                        tracedSVG
                        aspectRatio
                      }
                  }
              }
                  }
                  fields {
                  slug
                  }
                  excerpt
              }
              }
          }
          }
    `}
    render={data => <Gallery data={data} {...props} />}
    />
)
```

Thanks!!